# Why doesn't the data I'm receiving from a peer match the expected output?

Tags: c, hex, bittorrent

In my spare time, I have been working on implementing a BitTorrent client in C. Currently it communicates with the tracker, connects to the swarm, requests pieces of the torrent file from peers, and receives pieces of the torrent file. However, when it comes to verifying that the received piece is correct (by taking a SHA1 hash and comparing it to the hash provided in the .torrent metadata), it always fails.

To debug this, I downloaded a torrent with a known-working BitTorrent client, and then modified my own BitTorrent implementation to request and download only the very beginning of the torrent (the first piece). I then compared the two files with Emacs' hexl-mode.

Known good:

```
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
...
00008000: 0143 4430 3031 0100 4c49 4e55 5820 2020  .CD001..LINUX   
00008010: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00008020: 2020 2020 2020 2020 5562 756e 7475 2031          Ubuntu 1
00008030: 312e 3034 2069 3338 3620 2020 2020 2020  1.04 i386
```

My implementation:

```
00000000: a616 f132 7f00 0080 5066 0000 0000 0080  ...2....Pf......
00000010: 5066 0000 0000 0060 3b62 0000 0000 0098  Pf.....`;b......
00000020: 3b62 0000 0000 00d0 3b62 0000 0000 0008  ;b......;b......
00000030: 3c62 0000 0000 0040 3c62 0000 0000 0078  <b.....@<b.....x
00000040: 3c62 0000 0000 00b0 3c62 0000 0000 00e8  <b......<b......
00000050: 3c62 0000 0000 0020 3d62 0000 0000 0058  <b..... =b.....X
00000060: 3d62 0000 0000 0090 3d62 0000 0000 00c8  =b......=b......
00000070: 3d62 0000 0000 0000 3e62 0000 0000 0038  =b......>b.....8
...
0000d000: 0243 4430 3031 0100 004c 0049 004e 0055  .CD001...L.I.N.U
0000d010: 0058 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020  .X. . . . . . . 
0000d020: 0020 0020 0020 0020 0055 0062 0075 006e  . . . . .U.b.u.n
0000d030: 0074 0075 0020 0031 0031 002e 0030 0034  .t.u. .1.1...0.4
0000d040: 0020 0069 0033 0038 0000 0000 0000 0000  . .i.3.8........
```

I figured, then, that I must be writing the received piece to the incorrect offset, resulting in the correct data occuring at the wrong location in the file. To verify this, I fired up gdb and inspected the very beginning of the first piece after receiving it from a peer, expecting it to contain all zeroes, like the beginning of the known-good file.

```
(gdb) break network.c:40
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402fe7: file network.c, line 40.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/robb/slug/slug 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7fffcb58d700 (LWP 12936)]
[Thread 0x7fffcb58d700 (LWP 12936) exited]
ANNOUNCE: 50 peers.
CONNECTED: 62.245.41.28
CONNECTED: 89.178.142.45
CONNECTED: 66.65.166.17
...
UNCHOKE: 95.26.0.1
Requested piece 0 from peer 95.26.0.1.
UNCHOKE: 202.231.116.163
PIECE: #0 from 95.26.0.1

Breakpoint 1, handle_piece (p=0x42d7e0) at network.c:41
41       memcpy(p->torrent->mmap + length, &p->message[9], REQUEST_LENGTH);
(gdb) p off
$1 = 0
(gdb) p index
$2 = 0
(gdb) p p->message[9]
$3 = 46 '.'
(gdb) p p->message[10]
$4 = 67 'C'
(gdb) p p->message[11]
$5 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p p->message[12]
$6 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p p->message[13]
$7 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p p->message[14]
$8 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p p->message[15]
$9 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p p->message[16]
$10 = 128 '\200'
(gdb) p p->message[17]
$11 = 46 '.'
(gdb) p p->message[18]
$12 = 67 'C'
```

As you can see, the data I received from the peer doesn't contain all zeroes like the beginning of the known-good file. Why?

The full source of my program is availabe at https://github.com/robertseaton/slug.

Comment: That's a bit large for someone here to go debugging for you. Can't you reduce the code to just the network IO (if that's where the problem lies?). Have you debugged immediately after the bufferevent_read() calls as that is what you are receiving, without any other changes from your code. Have you verified the parameters that are used to call it? What happens when network.c get_msg() line 55 bufferevent_read() fails? Does it return -1? That might be why your "LINUX" string bytes are all widened. Also network.c read_prefix() line 78 you're reading into &p->message_length - is that correct?

Comment: It is not clear how you receive the data. Did you take little endian and big endian encoding into consideration. Internet protocols  always transmits data in big endian encoding.

Comment: You seem to have both 64 bit bitfields ("global_bitfield) and 8 bit bitfields (mostly temporal), all with only one bit used. You also have 8 bit bitfields where all the bits are used. I presume the protocol uses all the bits it can in the messages, but why do you spread them out when receiving them? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The 64 bit global_bitfield holds the combined information of all the bitfields, so it's possible that more than 1 bit will be used. The reason that I've spread out the bitfields when receiving them is just so that I can easily check if a bit is set or not by using array addressing. I will probably change this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails to take into account that bufferevent_read may fail and return a negative amount:

```
void get_msg (struct bufferevent* bufev, struct Peer* p)
{
     uint64_t amount_read = p->message_length - p->amount_pending;
     int64_t message_length = bufferevent_read(bufev, &p->message[amount_read],  p->amount_pending);
```

Replace with:

```
void get_msg (struct bufferevent* bufev, struct Peer* p)
{
 uint64_t amount_read = p->message_length - p->amount_pending;
 int64_t message_length = bufferevent_read(bufev, &p->message[amount_read], p->amount_pending);

 /* possible bufferevent_read found nothing */
 if (message_length < 0)
      message_length = 0;
```

Comment: I think you mean if(message_length < 0)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source I found this in network.c:

```
memcpy(&index, &p->message[1], sizeof(index));
memcpy(&off, &p->message[5], sizeof(off));

index = ntohl(index);
off = ntohl(off);
length = index * p->torrent->piece_length + off;

#ifdef DEBUG
if (off == 0)
   printf("PIECE: #%d from %s\n", index, inet_ntoa(p->addr.sin_addr));
#endif

memcpy(p->torrent->mmap + length, &p->message[9], REQUEST_LENGTH);
p->torrent->pieces[index].amount_downloaded += REQUEST_LENGTH;
```

I think the last two lines are intended to be:

```
memcpy(p->torrent->mmap + length, &p->message[9], length);
p->torrent->pieces[index].amount_downloaded += length;
```

BTW REQUEST_LENGTH = 16K.
More probably this "length-thing" should be p->message_length, or (p->message_length - 9)

The other bug is probably a strlen()+1 type of bug.